# Javascripts to read all headers of resources in a page

Tags: javascript, http-headers, bookmarklet, tampermonkey

This might be a silly question, but if you don't ask you don't know. I'm building a "tool" which will need information from all resources loaded in a page. The script is executed via a bookmark in chrome so I do not have access to the code itself.

So, is there any way of reading the headers of all the objects loaded when accessing a website (css, javascript, etc), or do I need to insert some kind of script with tampermonkey to intercept them during page load?

/Patrik

Comment: If it can be done, it will probably have to be a browser extension, not a bookmarklet.

Comment: I suspected as much. I will look into tampermonkey unless someone else has an idea of how to do it.